# String format output

Tags: python

Having a source program like below:

```
from string import Template
s=Template('$x,glorious $x!')
print s.substitute(x='slurm')
print s
print Template
```

and Output like below:

```
slurm,glorious slurm!
<string.Template object at 0x024955D0>
<class'string.Template'>
```

Why?The last outputs I can't understand.

Comment: because you are printing a string.Template instance and then just the class Template ...

Comment: Thanks.I make a mistake ,I think s.substitute will change original array.lol

Comment: @M.r No, substitute doesn't change the original Template, it returns a new string rendered from the template.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are creating a template:

```
s=Template('$x,glorious $x!')
```

Now you are parsing the template, replacing x with slurm:

```
print s.substitute(x='slurm')
```

Please notice, the above call returns a new string which is what you want to store in a new variable if you need to use it somewhere else.

You are printing s which is a Template object:

```
print s
```

You are printing Template which is a class you imported:

```
print Template
```

So probably this is what you wanted:

```
from string import Template
s=Template('$x,glorious $x!')
result = s.substitute(x='slurm')
print result
```